# When a mathematician says $f(y,x)$ is strictly increasing in $x$, what do they mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

when someone says $f(x,y)$ is increasing in $x$,
do they mean partial differentiation $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ or total differentiation $\frac{d f(x,y)}{d x}$?

If $y=h(x)$, then $f(x,y) = f(x,h(x))$ increases in $x$ in a partial sense, but $f(x,y)$ may decrease in a total sense.

Comment: It means that for each fixed $y$, $f(x_1, y) > f(x_2, y)$ whenever $x_ 1>x_2$. Also, I think your last paragraph is a bit careless with notation....

Comment: In addition to what Bongers said, this would mean (assuming $f$ is a nice smooth function) that $\partial f / \partial x$ is always positive.

Comment: So then, Suppose I have $y=h(x)$, and I say that $f(x,y)$ is increasing in $x$ when $f(x_1,h(x_3))>f(x_2,h(x_3))$ whenever $x_1>x_2$ for all $x_3$ ? or should I say $f(x,y)$ is increasing in $x$ if $f(x_1,h(x_1))>f(x_2,h(x_2))$ for all $x_1>x_2$?

Answer (score 1):

"$f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing in $y$" means that, for every $y_1, y_2$, and $x$ we have

$$y_1<y_2\Rightarrow f(x,y_1)<f(x,y_2)$$